# Cancan with rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
       user ||= User.new 

         if user and user.admin?
           can :access, :rails_admin
           can :dashboard
            if user.has_role? :superadmin       
               can :manage, :all
             elsif user.has_role? :admin
               can :manage, [Event]

             end   
         end 
        end
```

Even if I specify can :manage, :all/can :access,:rails_admin can :dashboard  and remove everything - it still directs me to home page with Access denied error. Here is my application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to '/', notice: 'Access Denied'
  end 
 end
```

What's happening here?!

Comment: Are you actually an admin? Otherwise you should grant yourself admin rights through your console before being able to do anything.

Comment: @rails4guides.com: I do have admin privileges. It doesn't work though. The user information itself is not going inside the ability class. The problem is even more when the user doesn't exist (guest user). It goes into too many redirects. I am making it work using can :manage :all inside for now. When I use authorize_resource class:false - it works when I'm logged in but not when I'm logged out

Comment: Hmm, I currently don't have time to  really look into it, but one small note: You should consider using the gem CanCanCan, which is maintained in contrary to its predecessor CanCan.